# Optimise initialisation of several np.zeros() arrays of fixed size in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to optimise the process of initialising python `np.zeros()` arrays. Right now I just have a list of them like

```
import numpy as np

n_elements = 10

a = np.zeros(n_elements)
b = np.zeros(n_elements)
c = np.zeros(n_elements)
d = np.zeros(n_elements)
```

Do you know how I could make this bulk of code shorter?

I know that

```
a = b = c = d = np.zeros(n_elements)
```

Is not an option, since it will be all assigned to one memory slot.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` directly to generate a 2D array:

```
a,b,c,d = np.zeros((4, n_elements))
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you unaccept the answer? A loops seems not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop

```
a, b, c, d = [np.zeros(n_elements) for _ in range(4)]
```